# How to pass an argument to ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor?

Tags: java, multithreading, scheduledexecutorservice

How would i pass an argument to the ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor?

I have the following code. You will notice that i have declared a variable 'num' and it is passed as an argument to exampleFunction(). exampleFunction contains a ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor. I want to be able to use the variable 'num' inside public void run(). Is there any way i can do that?

```
     class Test {
     ...
     int num;
     exampleFunction(num);
     ...

     public void exampleFunction(num) {
         ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor exec = new ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor(1);
         exec.schedule(new Runnable() {
             public void run() {
                 ...do something here...
                 ...something with 'num' here...
                 ...i get an error when i try to use 'num' here
             }
         }, 10, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
     }

}
```

Comment: please put a bit more effort in tagging your question: it's plain java multithreading, unrelated to swing/x, java-ee

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Did you try changing `exampleFunction(num)` as `exampleFunction(final int num)`? Since run method is in an inner class all external bindings need to be final.

```
public void exampleFunction(final int num) { // final int here
     ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor exec = new ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor(1);
     exec.schedule(new Runnable() {
         public void run() {
             ...do something here...
             ...something with 'num' here...
             ...i get an error when i try to use 'num' here
         }
     }, 10, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
 }
```

Comment: This worked! Would it still work if the value of 'num' keeps changing. If 'num' was in a loop and it's value kept changing in the loop, and exampleFunction() is called for each value of 'num', then would declaring num as 'final int num' still work?

Answer (score 4):

Either make `num` `final` or `static` (or accessible from a `static` method), or else create your own `Runnable`.

```java
class MyRunnable implements Runnable {
    int num;

    public MyRunnable(int num) {
        this.num = num;
    }

    public void run() { ... }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

declare you variable num `final` and you will be able to use it inside the `Run()` method.

Write this instead

```
final int num;
```